# Is there a way to use a Modal in a React Class Component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, material-ui

I am trying to render a single draft once I click the modal, instead of navigating to the other component... if that makes sense... im getting to display it but then it redirects me because of the Link.. but if i dont add the Link then I loose my draftId on url

This is part of my code

```
class Drafts extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchAllDrafts()
  }

  render() {
    const drafts = this.props.drafts

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Table aria-label="a dense table" className="myaccount-table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell align="center">
                <div className="date-content">Date</div>
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">Content</TableCell>
              <TableCell> </TableCell>
              <TableCell> </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {drafts.map((draft) => (
              <TableRow key={draft.id}>
                <TableCell>
                  <div className="datecontent">{draft.createdAt}</div>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <div className="content">{draft.content} </div>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <Link to={`/drafts/${draft.id}`}>
                    <Popup
                      trigger={<button className="button"> Read </button>}
                      modal
                      nested
                    >
                      <SingleDraft />
                      {/* <Button color="primary">
                        Read
                      </Button> */}
                    </Popup>
                  </Link>
```

the  is comming from another class component

```
class SingleDraft extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchDraft(this.props.match.params.draftId)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.singleDraft.content} </p>
        <Link to={`/texteditor/${this.props.singleDraft.id}`}>
          <button>Update</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried and what are the issues you have faced.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the `draftId` as a prop?

```
<Popup
    trigger={<button className="button"> Read </button>}
    modal
    nested
>
    <SingleDraft draftId={draft.id} />
    {/* <Button color="primary">Read</Button> */}
</Popup>
```

And in your component.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchDraft(this.props.draftId)
}
```

Comment: thanks!Tried it but not working :( as I have it, it does render but for one second, and then I get redirected to singleDraft component... and i dont want that

Comment: You need to remove the link component so it doesn't redirect you.